# css overflow on both parent and child div

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to display two lists in a container where:

- the label list is always fixed to the left
- the content list can scroll horizontally as the content is long
- when scrolling vertically at any place in the container, both lists should scroll as a whole

My current approach is far from satisfactory - the label list is not fixed; and when scrolling vertically in the content list, the label list is not scrolled along.

How to fix it?

Here's snippet:

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#labelList {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

#contentList {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.row {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="labelList">
    <div class="row">label</div>
    <div class="row">label</div>
    <div class="row">label</div>
    <div class="row">label</div>
  </div>
  <div id="contentList">
    <div class="row">super super super super super duper long text</div>
    <div class="row">super super super super super duper long text</div>
    <div class="row">super super super super super duper long text</div>
    <div class="row">super super super super super duper long text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's [codepen](https://codepen.io/xuanmmt/pen/deJBGM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach uses some javascript to set the height of the content, which was the only limitation I ran into when creating your layout. You can see the issue by removing the script.
There may be a better answer...

```js
var content = document.querySelector('#contentList'),
  numberOfRows = content.children.length;

content.style.height = (numberOfRows * 50) + "px";
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#labelList {
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  position: absolute;
}

#contentList {
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-left: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.row {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="labelList">
    <div class="row">label</div>
    <div class="row">label</div>
    <div class="row">label</div>
    <div class="row">label</div>
  </div>
  <div id="contentList">
    <div class="row">super super super super super duper long text</div>
    <div class="row">super super super super super duper long text</div>
    <div class="row">super super super super super duper long text</div>
    <div class="row">super super super super super duper long text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing solution, thanks! But why is it able to scroll vertically when there's no `overflow-y` on the container?

Comment: `overflow-y` is defaulting 'visible' or 'auto' I presume? Not sure to be honest